# Oracle Query to return a single row

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query that returns the fifth row as output plus two additional columns capturing time from the first and third row as time of day and Shipped time respectively.What distinguishes the rows is the last and next status columns.

Below is my query and output.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
         SLMCU AS "BUSINESSUNIT",
         SLDOCO AS "ORDERNO",
         SLDCTO AS "ORDERTYPE",
         SLAN8 AS "CUSTOMERNO",
         ABALPH AS "CUSTOMERNAME",
         SLLITM AS "ITEMNO",
         SLDSC1 AS "DESCRIPTION",
         SLDSC2 AS "DESCRIPTION2",
         SLLTTR AS "LAST STATUS",
         SLNXTR AS "NEXT STATUS",
         CASE SLTRDJ
            WHEN 0 THEN TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (1 + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
            ELSE TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SLTRDJ + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
         END
            AS "ORDER DATE",
         CASE SLADDJ
            WHEN 0 THEN TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (1 + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
            ELSE TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SLADDJ + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
         END
            AS "SHIPPED DATE",
         SLTDAY AS "TIME",
         SLUORG / 10000 AS "ORDER QUANTITY",
         SLSOQS / 10000 AS "SHIPPED QUANTITY"
     FROM PRODDTA.F42199 INNER JOIN PRODDTA.F0101 ON SLAN8 = ABAN8 WHERE SLDOCO = 19437443
  -- WHERE ((SLLTTR = 520 AND SLNXTR = 540) OR (SLLTTR = 620 AND SLNXTR = 582)) AND SLDOCO = 19437443
ORDER BY "LAST STATUS" ASC;
```

[image]

removed some columns for better visibility.
[image]

Desired output

[image]

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text. Simplify the problem ([mcve]), and use formatted text instead of images for sample table data and expected result.

Comment: @jarlh click on the image to view enlarged version

Comment: This is possible but quite expensive I think because we would need 3 calls of your query to get first, third and fifth values. Or we would need to write a procedure. Are you sure you want to achieve such a thing ?

Comment: @Gosfly yes i want too but using the most efficient method. Suggestions will equally be helpful.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with DDL statements for your tables, DML statements for your example data, your expected output (as formatted text, not images) and a detailed description (in English, not code) of the transformation that you expect to occur to get from the input to the output. Please help us to help you as without example data that we can easily copy and run this makes it so much harder to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the rows an incrementing row number according to your ordering criteria (`NEXT_STATUS`) and then use analytic functions to find values for the 1st and 3rd row and then filter to return only the 5th row:

```sql
WITH your_query AS (
  -- paste your query here
)
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN time END ) OVER () AS time_of_day,
         MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN time END ) OVER () AS shipped_time
  FROM   (
    SELECT q.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY next_status ) AS rn
    FROM   your_query q
  ) t
  WHERE rn IN ( 1, 3, 5 )
)
WHERE  rn = 5;
```

---

Alternate version:

```sql
WITH your_query AS (
  -- paste your query here
)
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         MAX( CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 1 THEN time END ) OVER () AS time_of_day,
         MAX( CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 3 THEN time END ) OVER () AS shipped_time,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT *,
    FROM   your_query
    ORDER BY next_status
  ) t
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
)
WHERE  rn = 5;
```

---

**Update for multiple `ORDERNO`**:

```sql
WITH your_query AS (
  -- paste your query here
)
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN time END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY orderno ) AS time_of_day,
         MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN time END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY orderno ) AS shipped_time
  FROM   (
    SELECT q.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY orderno ORDER BY next_status ) AS rn
    FROM   your_query q
  ) t
  WHERE rn IN ( 1, 3, 5 )
)
WHERE  rn = 5;
```

Comment: As I said in comment, this is unfortunately very very very very expansive...

Comment: @Gosfly Please can you justify that statement.

Comment: @MTO your solution is simple and worked like charm, only that I need to apply it to a table that has over a million rows with several order numbers. Is there a way I can make the query run much faster. Please also explain what the SELECT t.* and q.* does in your solution.

Comment: `q.*` selects all the columns from the query aliased `q` (i.e. your query) and `t.*` selects all the columns from the query aliased `t` (i.e. the inner-most query that is all the columns from your query plus the row number).

Comment: The only way I can think to make this method speed this up is if you can remove the `DISTINCT` clause from your query. It is already only going to parse your query once and there is nothing it is using that is not required to get your data. The best you can do is to implement all the solutions that people have given and find the one that is most performant for your data.

Comment: If you have a lot of rows in your table "your_query" it will have to calculate both max(case) over( [all rows] ) for each row which is so expansive''. I tried it with 18 000 rows and it took around 700 seconds ... I wonder how much time did it take on a million rows ?

Comment: @Gosfly Any way you do it you have to process all the rows as you need to use `ORDER BY` over all the rows to get the correct 1st, 3rd and 5th rows. I've updated it so that the `MAX` is only performed over 5 rows.

Comment: @Gosfly [`ROWNUM` is a pseudo-column](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) and exists for all queries.

Comment: Yes my bad, thought it was mysql, you're right ! It should be better now for performances : went from 700 seconds to less than one. Great solution here.

Comment: @MTO I have used your example but only a single row is returned and i'm expecting several because I've got many "ORDERNO". I have updated my query.

Comment: @gosfly what am i missing since you were able to successfully run it with 18000 rows.

Comment: @E.Ogony It only returns 1 row because that is what your desired output in the question asks for. If you don't provide us with the correct data and the correct question then we can't answer the question you want because you haven't asked that question.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I will post another question shortly.

Comment: @E.Ogony BTW, I had also updated my answer to return multiple rows.

Comment: @MTO your post 'Update for multiple ORDERNO' produced the results I wanted. Thank you for your patience and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the 5th row;

```
select * from (<<your_query>> where rownum<=5 order by rownum desc) x where rownum <= 1;
```

Now for your requirenments, do something like below (You may have to tweak the query a bit);

```
with row1 as (select * from (<<your_query>> where rownum<=5 order by rownum desc) x where rownum <= 1)
select (select time from (<<your_query>> where rownum<=3 order by rownum desc) y where rownum <= 1) as time,
select (select shippedtime from (<<your_query>> where rownum<=1 order by rownum desc)) as shippedtime,
BUSINESSUNIT,
ORDERNO,
ORDERTYPE,
CUSTOMERNO,
CUSTOMERNAME,
ITEMNO,
DESCRIPTION,
DESCRIPTION2,
"LAST STATUS",
"NEXT STATUS",
"ORDER DATE",
"ORDER QUANTITY",
"SHIPPED QUANTITY"
from
<<your_query>>
where 
 "NEXT STATUS" = (select "NEXT STATUS" from row1)
 AND "LAST STATUS" = (select "LAST STATUS" from row1);
```

replace `<<your_query>>` with the query you put in the question, and it should work.
Also, you may have to add the where and order by from my query to yours, for the query to work.

Comment: MT0's answer could be a bit cleaner than mine on first look...Although, both could work just fine.

Comment: Thank you @shivam for taking time to post this answer. If i'm to do this to a whole table with many order numbers how will the query look like?

Comment: If the requirements remain the same (1st rows shippedtime and 3rd rows time) and there is no change in the columns that you need from the table, I believe this query should work fine over a large dataset as well. You will have to try it out once.

Comment: I updated the answer a little. You may have to edit your query a bit for my answer to work properly. (Add the "where" and "order by" criteries of the "rownum" from my query to yours)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth_value` analytical function.

First take all the columns having unique values and then using `nth_value` choose which values to be displayed for that column in the result and use `distinct` as following.

```
Select distinct
<all_columns except last_status, next_status, time, shipped_date and shipped_time>,
nth_value(last_status, 5) over (order by last_status) as last_status,
nth_value(next_status, 5) over (order by last_status) as next_status,
nth_value(time, 1) over (order by last_status) as time,
nth_value(shipped_date, 5) over (order by last_status) as shipped_date,
nth_value(shipped_time, 3) over (order by last_status) as shipped_time
From (your_query)
```

Cheers!!